# Group by month in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have this query (for Oracle) :

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CREATIONDATE, 'MM.YYYY'), 'MM.YYYY') as month,
SUM(count(*)) over (order by to_date(TO_CHAR(CREATIONDATE, 'MM.YYYY'),'MM.YYYY') ) as total
FROM person
GROUP BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CREATIONDATE, 'MM.YYYY'), 'MM.YYYY')
```

It counts the number of people, group by month and in the correct order :

Ex. 01.2014, 02.2014, ... , 01.2015. 02.2015, ...

It's working but :

1. Is there a better way to do it ?
2. I need to have a single query for Oracle, Sql-Server and PostGre SQL. Is there a way to do it ? All I can use String.Replace in my application to slightly modify the query..

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a single query with the same sytax that will work with Oracle, SQL Server and Postgres?

Comment: Yes, I want to know if this is possible, at least with minor modifications at runtime in my application with String.Replace

Comment: Check my answer. I considered only Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The part `to_date(TO_CHAR(CREATIONDATE, 'MM.YYYY'),'MM.YYYY')` is unnecessary in the `Analytic window` and `Group by` expression. And, why do you convert the literal to date again in the select? You just need to use `TO_CHAR` to display the required format.

check this :

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT SYSDATE dt FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL< 11
  3    )
  4  SELECT TO_CHAR(dt,'MM.YYYY') dt,
  5    SUM(COUNT(*)) over (order by dt ) cnt
  6  FROM DATA
  7  GROUP BY dt
  8  /

DT             CNT
------- ----------
10.2014         10

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact I added the TO_DATE for an other reason... (the order by of my query didn't work where I used the query, in a reports software...). But I'm still looking for a single query for all databases if there is a way to do it...

Comment: i don't have other databases to verify, neither I know any syntax for other databases. I am a poor Oracle developer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are compatible date functions across the three databases.  You can come close with something like:

```
select month(creationdate) as mon, year(creationdate) as yr,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by min(creationdate)) as total
from person
group by month(creationdate), year(creationdate);
```

The above works in Oracle and SQL Server.  For Postgres, you can then easily define `month()` and `year()` functions.

You can use your version or use `extract(month from creationdate), extract(year from creationdate)` in the above version for Postgres and Oracle.